# discord.js@13.0.0, member.timeout

Tags: node.js, npm, discord, discord.js, bots

I've attempted to make a timeout command a "mute" command, but I keep on getting the error `member.timeout is not a function` any idea on a fix for this? I haven't been able to find anything on this anywhere.

Commands code:

```
const BaseCommand = require('../../utils/structures/BaseCommand');
const { timeout } = require('discord.js')

module.exports = class MuteCommand extends BaseCommand {
  constructor() {
    super('mute', 'moderation', []);
  }

  async run(client, message, args) {
    try {
      let member = message.mentions.members.first();
      if(!member) return message.channel.send("No user was given.")
      const time = args[0]
      await member.timeout(5 * 60 * 1000)
      .then(message.channel.send("Muted user"))
      .catch(message.channel.send("Unable to mute user"));
    } catch (error) {
      message.channel.send(`Error:\n\`\`\`\n${error}\`\`\``)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Timeout was released after 13.0, update discord.js to the latest stable version

Comment: thank you, on the docs said it was added in 13.0.0 so was a bit confused

Comment: what permissions does it need to run? it's got the scopes of bot with admin privileges, keep's saying "DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions"

Comment: Probably because it's trying to affect an administrator or someone with a higher status than the bot

Comment: Timeout was in fact released in 13.4.0, not 13.0.0.

Comment: ok thank you massive help, and it was due to the user being affected having admin privileges with the permissions being denied